# Generate a custom unique id every-time new row is inserted in SQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**What I have**
So i have a table with lets say 3 columns(it actually has a lot more but for example's sake) lets say `id`,`name` and `email`. I have a webpage where user enters `name` and `email` and and using mysqli in php it gets saved into a MySQL database, `id` gets generated by php using auto-increment, so it goes like 1,2,3... and so on.
**What I want**
I don't want the id to just be an integer, I want it to be a combination of alphabets and digits, `eg.- B201`. I want to define the rules for which alphabets to use in which case, and I might also want to define parts of the number myself and parts of it will be auto-incremented.
Lets say if the email entered by user is a gmail email then I will want the first character to be G, if its yahoo it will be Y etc. `eg.- G201,Y201`.
Now the first and second digit I want to be indicating month, so if its Nov then id should be `G111`.
The last digit should auto-increment for every new entry.
I looked on google to find something to help but couldn't find anything good(maybe my googling skills sucks).
**Where I am stuck**
Deciding the first three characters in php is pretty easy, I can check the email string posted the user and decide the first alphabet and for next digits I can check the current datetime and decide it by current month.
The real problem is the last part, which is auto-increment and I can't figure out how to do that. How will php script know when inserting a new row that what was the value inserted last time so that it can add a +1 to the auto-increment value this time.
So if some one can help me with generating a similar string in php so that I can save push it in the database I will very much appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why don't you generate the ID you are looking for and check for it's existance in the database?

Comment: i can't, hold on, i will edit the question and explain it a bit more.

Comment: Before insertion select max(id), get number from the result using substr, add one, concat that number with alphabet, insert, if there are no ids statically put 1 as id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of generating the integer yourself, you could use the mysqli last insert id:

```
// Note: you must call the mysqli_insert_id()
// function  after the insert query

$generate_id = mysqli_insert_id( $connection );

// Get the first character from the email server
// gmail.com will be: G
// yahoo.com will be: Y
// and so on...
$generate_char = strtoupper( explode( '@', $email_here)[ 1 ][ 0 ] );

// Concatenate the generated values
$unique_id = $generate_char . $generate_id;
```

That's it.

Note that string can be manipulated as an array, for example:

```
$str = 'gmail.com';
```

To get the first letter: g you can use an array notation like so:

```
$first_letter = $str[ 0 ];
```

Comment: `$generate_id = mysqli_insert_id( $connection );`  Thanks this is what I needed. Can't understand why people keep downvoting my questions.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: BTW docs say `mysqli_insert_id();` returns the id generated by last query, what if I have made other queries after last insertion, like read the contents or table or edit it. Will `mysqli_insert_id();` still work.

Comment: The function is: mysqli insert id ( descriptive enough ): this means get the last insertion id generated. This has nothing to do with select or update query. Further more, you're getting the last insert id after the insert  query has ben executed, a conflict here is impossible, except if you're inserting into another table after the the one returning the last insert id.